# Losing CreatedOn data when modifying a record in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to save the `AuditLog` data in Entity Framework in my ASP.NET Core Web API, and I'm using SQLite as my database. I tried to override the `SaveChangesAsync()` method to track them.

But the `CreatedBy` and `CreatedOn` values are lost every time I modify a record.

Here's the overridden version of `SaveChangesAsync()` method and a sample entity:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

public EvaDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(options)
{
    _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (!_contextAccessor.IsLoginRequeust())
    {
        // Grab all entity entries
        var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity is DomainObject && (e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified));
        var userId = _contextAccessor.GetUserId();

        foreach (var entityEntry in entityEntries)
        {
            // Add current datetime for modified state
            ((DomainObject)entityEntry.Entity).ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
            ((DomainObject)entityEntry.Entity).ModifiedBy = userId;

            // Add current datetime for added state
            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((DomainObject)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                ((DomainObject)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedBy = userId;
            }
        }
    }

    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

[image]

Comment: How are your entites defined?

Comment: Here is a the Instrument Entity definition:

public class Instrument : DomainObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: So, CreatedOn does not belong to the model ? I.e. when the entity is loaded, the old value is not loaded, hence having null / default values.

Comment: So you mean if the CreatedOn propery was not inherited from DomainObject class and it was defined right on the entity, the values wouldn't have been null?

Comment: If it's inherited, it should be all good indeed. But maybe there was some small mistake or detail overlooked? Could you share some [mcve] that includes the model definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually achieved what I was looking for but I'm not happy with the solution, here's what I did:

```
// Check if entry state is added mode
var isAddedState = entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added;

// Detect trackeble properties
entityEntry.Property("ModifiedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
entityEntry.Property("ModifiedBy").CurrentValue = userId;
entityEntry.Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = isAddedState ? DateTime.Now : entityEntry.Property("CreatedOn").OriginalValue;
entityEntry.Property("CreatedBy").CurrentValue = isAddedState ? userId : entityEntry.Property("CreatedBy").OriginalValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you can't set the properties directly on [EntityEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry?view=efcore-8.0).[Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1.entity?view=efcore-8.0) as that is `virtual` and not the actual entity.

Try this instead,

```
foreach (var entityEntry in entityEntries)
{
    if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        entityEntry.Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
        entityEntry.Property("CreatedBy").CurrentValue = userId;
    }

    entityEntry.Property("ModifiedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
    entityEntry.Property("ModifiedBy").CurrentValue = userId;
}
```

That said, overriding `SaveChangesAsync` and using `ChangeTracker` is unusual. You can avoid the vargaries of `ChangeTracker` altogether by setting your properties in the actual domain objects in a different layer (higher layer) or by using [an interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) (lower layer) assuming you can get the context injected.

Comment: Thanks alot, but still got the same issue